# tomcat null pointer at startup

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have created a netbeans web project with maven, But when i start tomcat it gives me this error:

```
    14-Dec-2016 00:08:37.611 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Error during mapping
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.internalMapWrapper(Mapper.java:842)
    at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getRequestDispatcher(ApplicationContext.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getRequestDispatcher(ApplicationContextFacade.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getRequestDispatcher(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:303)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRequestDispatcher(ServletRequestWrapper.java:291)...and other exceptions
```

What is the error? Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:
This is web.xml deployment descriptor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AuthorServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.avantipopolo.servlets.AuthorServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AuthorServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/AuthorServlet</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/AuthorServlet/new</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/AuthorServlet/edit</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/AuthorServlet/delete</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: And your Tomcat version is ...?

Comment: my version of Tomcat is 8.0.27

Comment: You'll have to show us your code (at least the `@WebServlet` annotations) and/or `web.xml` - it seems there is an error in mapping a path to a servlet.